# Install Windows 10 on sdb2, when Linux in sda1

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I'm going to install Windows 10 to sdb2 via VirtualBox, and then manually edit grub conf file, so I could dual boot linux and windows. Linux in sda1. /home in sdb1.

Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

> Will it work?

No, because dual-boot has nothing to do with VirtualBox and using VirtualBox you'd be running a virtual machine, a guest OS running inside a host OS and that has nothing to do with dual-booting.

Comment: I'm going to use sdb (My second hard disk) like raw disk on VirtualBox.

Comment: Not a dual-boot.